# Laravel Broadcast event not working with custom namespace in frontend using Laravel Echo and Pusher JS

Tags: laravel, events, broadcast

I have created a Laravel Broadcast event in a custom namespace (GainHQ\Conversation\Events), which is not working when listening to it in my frontend application using Laravel Echo and Pusher JS. However, if the event is located in the App\Events namespace, it works fine.

Here's my event code:

```
namespace GainHQ\Conversation\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ConversationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $message;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): PrivateChannel
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('conversation-channel.' . $this->message['conversation_id']);
    }
}
```

And here's my JavaScript code for listening to the event:

```
Echo.private('conversation-channel.' + conversationId)
    .listen('ConversationEvent', (e) => {
        // Handle the event here
    });
```

in provider boot:

```
Event::listen(ConversationEvent::class, function ($event) {
     return $event->broadcastWith();
});
```